# Last Updated record with timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get last updated date and time of all the record present in a table using the following query.

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN),id FROM TABLE_NAME
```

For some of the table its displaying result correctly, but for others I got following error message (to be specific I'm using tables from HR Schema which are auto generated)

> ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1
>
> 8181. 00000 -  "specified number is not a valid system change number"
>
> *Cause:    supplied scn was beyond the bounds of a valid scn.
> *Action:   use a valid scn.

Why I'm getting this error message? Before running the query I ran a couple of insert and update queries for the same table.

Thank you

Comment: Also, it's better to have an extra columns to track data changes. ORA_ROWSCN is very unrealiable and doesn't work for old data (for e.g. your case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limitation in Oracle 10g and 9i you can only flash back withing 5 days. In Oracle 11g there is no limitation.

You can check the oldest available System change number (SCN) number in database.

Using this query

```
select min(SCN) min_scn from sys.smon_scn_time;
```

Using the SCN NUMBER from the above query you can get the last TIMESTAMP for the SCN

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP( scn number here) FROM dual;
```

If you check older SCN than minimum SCN then you will get the error.

source [link](http://www.nazmulhuda.info/ora-06512-at-sys-scn_to_timestamp)

Comment: `select min(SCN) min_scn from sys.smon_scn_time;` gives me "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". That is with SQL Developer on Oracle 11g.

Comment: @mivk :  since it is in the SYS schema, you need to be dba to read it (sys or system)

Answer (score 1):

`SCN` (system change number for last dml operation) is generated and remembered by the oracle for limited period. You are converting old scn to timestamp and error is raised.

`ORA_ROWSCN` has two behaviour. If tabe is created with `"NOROWDEPENDENCIES"` (default). ORA_ROWSCN  returns scn number for oracle data block.

If tabe is created with `"ROWDEPENDENCIES"`. `ORA_ROWSCN`  returns scn number for row.